# Upgrade Ruby 1.8.6 to Ruby 1.8.7 patch -level 72

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to run application server like ruby script/server

It says `/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl/cipher.rb:22: Cipher is not a module (TypeError)`.

So I followed the steps given in the [following link](http://iamclovin.posterous.com/how-to-solve-the-cipher-is-not-a-module-error).

When I've run the following command:

```
ruby extconf.rb
```

I've encountered the following error:

```
=== OpenSSL for Ruby configurator
===
=== Checking for system dependent stuff... 
=== checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no checking for socket() in -lsocket... no checking for assert.h... yes 
=== Checking for required stuff... 
=== checking for openssl/ssl.h... no 
=== Checking for required stuff failed. 
=== Makefile wasn't created. Fix the errors above. * extconf.rb failed *
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options.
Provided configuration options: 
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include 
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib 
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
--with-openssl-dir
--without-openssl-dir
--with-openssl-include
--without-openssl-include=${openssl-dir}/include
--with-openssl-lib 
--without-openssl-lib=${openssl-dir}/lib
--with-kerberos-dir
--without-kerberos-dir
--with-kerberos-include
--without-kerberos-include=${kerberos-dir}/include
--with-kerberos-lib 
--without-kerberos-lib=${kerberos-dir}/lib
--with-debug
--without-debug
--enable-debug 
--disable-debug
--with-nsllib
--without-nsllib
--with-socketlib
--without-socketlib
--with-openssl-config
--without-openssl-config
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems extconf failed to detect openssl development headers/libraries. You should install it or help extconf find it (if openssl development files already installed):

```
ruby extconf.rb --with-openssl-dir="prefix-on-file-system-where-openssl-files-resides"
ruby extconf.rb --with-openssl-include="include-files-location" \
                --with-oppenssl-lib="openssl-libs-location"
```